# AVAsset's "isPlayable" / "playable" check blocks and delays UI updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, avasset

In my app at some point the user can invoke video playing with tapping on an UI element, and then the following code segment will be executed:

```
self.loadingView.frame = _frameWhereItShouldBeLocated;
[self.loadSpinner startAnimating];  // self.loadSpinner is an UIActivityIndicatorView
self.loadingView.hidden = FALSE;

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileUrl];   // fileUrl is where is the video file is hosted, which is not a local path

if ([player.currentItem.asset isPlayable])
{

   if (!self.playerController) {
       self.playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
       self.playerController.transitioningDelegate = self;
       self.playerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
   }

   self.playerController.player = player;
   self.playerController.showsPlaybackControls = TRUE;

   [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.playerController animated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.playerController.player play];

}
```

I expect the loading view will be visible immediately after user's tap, and then after some time, the player controller is then presented and play the video. However, it happens that there is a significant delay before the loading view become visible.

This is what I expected:

```
User tap -> loading view shown -> (some time for loading the video, etc) -> play video
```

Instead this is what I've got:

```
User tap -> (significant time delay) -> loading view shown -> play video
```

After some debugging I found that the delay is caused by the `[player.currentItem.asset isPlayable]` call, i.e. the loading view only become visible after the call is returned. I tried to put the segment below the display of loading view in a `dispatch_async` call but it makes no different.

Is there anyway to handle this to make it behaves as expected?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer is in the introduction of AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `if ([player.currentItem.asset isPlayable])`

check this

```
if ((player.rate != 0) && (player.error == nil)) {
    // player is playing
}
```

Or 
You can add notification for `rate` property like below

```
[player addObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"rate"
                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                 context:NULL];
```

Then check if the new value for observed rate is zero, which means that playback has stopped for some reason, like reaching the end or stalling because of empty buffer.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"rate"]) {
        float rate = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] floatValue];
        if (rate == 0.0) {
            // Playback stopped
        } else if (rate == 1.0) {
            // Normal playback
        } else if (rate == -1.0) {
            // Reverse playback
        }
    }
}
```

For rate == 0.0 case, to know what exactly caused the playback to stop, you can do the following checks:

```
if (self.player.error != nil) {
    // Playback failed
}
if (CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime) >=
    CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration)) {
    // Playback reached end
} else if (!self.player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp) {
    // Not ready to play, wait until enough data is loaded
}
```

Based on above condition hide your indicator view.
And load your indicator view on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//load spinner
});
```